# python- Cannot create signed url for Google cloud storage object

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage

I use the code below to generate signed url for a file on Google cloud storage but when i click the link i got `SignatureDoesNotMatch`

```
from google.cloud.storage._signing import generate_signed_url
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials

signed_url = generate_signed_url(credentials=Credentials.from_service_account_file(google_cloud_platform__key_path),
                                     resource=self.canonicalized_resource,
                                     expiration=self.expiration,
                                     content_type=self.content_type
                                     )
```

Comment: this is a known issue, which hasn't been fixed yet. follow link to know more https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python/issues/50